I get extremely slow performance in Angular Google Maps when I have to load hundreds of markers
I'm rendering around 400 map advanced markers, however, these make my app extremely slow and I can't see anything that could cause this problem.
This is the code I have:
<div class="map-container" style="height: 100%;">
  <google-map #map height="100%" width="100%" [options]="mapOptions" mapId="myMapID">
      @for (marker of markers; track marker) {
        <map-advanced-marker #markerElem="mapAdvancedMarker" [position]="marker ?? {lat: 0, lng: 0}"  [title]="marker.title"
        (mapClick)="onMarkerClick(markerElem)"></map-advanced-marker>
      }
      <map-info-window #infoWindow>info window</map-info-window>
  </google-map>
</div>

onMarkerClick opens a new infowindow to show related info about the marker:
  onMarkerClick(marker: MapAdvancedMarker) {
    const contentString = 'some html here' 
    this.infoWindow.openAdvancedMarkerElement(marker.advancedMarker, contentString);
  }

I tried using clustering but I think that's not a solution, the performance is still slow and I saw other apps running hundreds of markers without grouping them, and the app was having a good performance.
Sadly the Angular Google Maps documentation is not that good and I didn't find anything that could cause this lag.
Also, I tried to run this in a blank project and I got the same result.

I got the same problem some time ago, as far as I know is a problem from the library, there is no way of fixing it yet. Try using the normal map markers.

The "normal map markers" are deprecated and cause a warning to show if you use them.

Yeah I know that. But they do the work, still works fine and don't have that big performance issue. Otherwise, give a solution instead of a useless comment.

The information is not useless, as witnessed by the number of questions asked about the deprecation warning on this site alone. You could update your answer to include the relevant information instead of biting my head off. My comment was meant to help future visitors understand the implications of going forward with your suggestion.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Hi i would like to avoid using deprecated stuff
